# How to inject ViewModelProvider.Factory into a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, androidx

In short: How can I inject a ViewModelProvider.Factory into my Fragment to get access to the appropriate ViewModel?

I have an activity with tabs managed by a BottomNavigationBar. Each tab screen is represented by a Fragment. Switching between tabs is done by replacing Fragments.

Each TabFragment has an associated ViewModel class. These ViewModel classes take arguments in the constructor, and for this reason I have to create a ViewModelProvider.Factory to use ViewModelProvider.

Naturally, my first instinct would be to inject this Factory into the fragment upon construction, and then retrieve a ViewModel instance via the ViewModelProvider:

```
class TabA(private val viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory) : Fragment() {
    ...
    tabAViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory)
            .get(TabAViewmodel::class.java)
    ...
}
```

Fragments, however, require no-arguments constructors. Instead instantiation can be done through a static factory method and simple arguments can be supplied through a Bundle, but it seems that this Bundle cannot contain complex types such as a ViewModelFactory.

How can I then inject my ViewModelFactory into the Fragment? Is dependency injection of custom types even possible for fragments?

Comment: Field injection. Hilt does the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60070233/cannot-resolve-viewmodelprovider-construction-in-a-fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a `Fragment` with constructor arguments you can use `FragmentFactory` - it is no longer a requirement to have no-arg constructors on fragments.

1. Create the injectable factory :

   ```
    class MyFragmentFactory @Inject constructor(private val viewModelFactoryTabA: ViewModelProvider.Factory) : FragmentFactory() {

    override fun instantiate(classLoader: ClassLoader, className: String): Fragment =
        when (loadFragmentClass(classLoader, className)) {
            TabA::class.java     -> TabA(viewModelFactoryTabA)
            else                 -> super.instantiate(classLoader, className)

        }
   ```

   }
2. Set the factory in parent Activity :

   ```
    class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject lateinit var fragmentFactory: MyFragmentFactory

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory = fragmentFactory
    }
   ```

   }

More info in the documentation : https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentFactory